# Advice on simple deployment of ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, deployment

I usually deploy updated ASP.NET web applications by simply copying the app's files to the virtual directory on the IIS server and overwriting any existing files, but a colleague claims that it's better to delete the files first before deploying the web app.

In scenarios where there are at least the same number of files in the updated app, I can't see any issue with deployment using copy and overwrite.

Any comments or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy paste should work without any issues (No need to delete and paste). The modified time stamp ensures code gets recompiled again, when a page request is made.